# Не могу прикрепить футер к низу страницы

Tags: html, css

Есть ли какая-нибудь возможность прикрепить футер к низу страницы, не изменяя разметку контейнера и мейна.

На данный момент пробовал все что умею и знаю:

1. менял позицию футера на `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`. Последнее свойство помогает, но я не хочу видеть футер всегда. Только в внизу, после последнего контейнера.
2. перетаскивал футер за пределы мейна и обратно. Тоже без особого результата.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Nunito+Sans|Roboto&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

html,
body,
header,
main {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-image: url(../images/extra_clean_paper.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#hero-header {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: dimgray;
  z-index: 2;
}

main:not {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 1em;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 3.125em 0.625em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.aboutme .col-40 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 39%;
}

.aboutme .col-60 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 59%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.hobbies .table-row {
  display: table-row;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid darkgrey;
}

.hobbies .table-row:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

.hobbies .table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.portfolio .col-50 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 49%;
}

.projects .flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.projects .col-33 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 33%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 33%;
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}

.projects .services-box {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 5px 0 5px;
}

footer {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<header id="link-hero-page">
  <div id="hero-header">
  </div>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <section id="link-main" class="aboutme container">
    <div class="col-40 left">
    </div>
    <article class="col-60 right">
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="link-hobbies" class="hobbies container">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-row">
        <article class="table-cell">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
        </div>
        <article class="table-cell">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <article class="table-cell">
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="link-portfolio" class="portfolio container">
    <article class="col-50 left">
    </article>
    <article class="col-50 right">
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="link-projects" class="projects container">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="col-33">
        <article class="services-box">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-33">
        <article class="services-box">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-33">
        <article class="services-box">
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="link-contacts" class="contacts container">

  </section>
</main>
<!--FOOTER-->
<footer>
  <address>
    <p style="text-align: center;">LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM</p>
   </address>
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0gxpakuo/

Comment: надо прикрепить к низу страницы или к низу экрана?

Comment: position: absolute у вас не прижимает футер к самому низу, потому что в вас задана высота 100%; html,
body,
header,
main {
  height: 100%;
}

Comment: сделайте header с фикс высотой (например header { height: 250px; } и уберите 
header {
  height: 100%;
}

Comment: @Skywave к низу страницы. К низу экрана прикрепляется со свойством fixed.

Comment: @Odyssey Немного не понимаю причем здесь header? Header должен быть по замыслу по высоте окна.

Answer (score 0):

Футер упал вниз сразу как только я убрал стиль `height: 100%` для `main`

```
html,
body,
header,
main { /* <-- убрал */
  height: 100%;
}
```

Но тогда лежащие внутри `section'ы` схлопнулись.

https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/df3cmv7x/3/

Другой вариант - просто положить футер в `main`

https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/df3cmv7x/5/

Comment: У меня тоже так получалось. Вся проблема в том, что `main { max-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }` имеет место быть :) Так же пробовал все это сделать путем изменения селектора `main` на `main:not(footer)`. Эффекта 0.

Comment: @worker, не понял в чем проблема =)

Comment: В вашем примере отсутствуем максимальная ширина main. Когда ее поставить, то футер обрезается в эти самые 960px.

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам мой "костыль", который не меняет твою разметку. Уверен что можно сделать лучше и проще, но это вроде бы то что Вам нужно. 
Вся суть в том чтобы накинуть сss свойство top с значением в пикселях для footer

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var height = $('body').outerHeight() + $('#link-hero-page').outerHeight() + $('#link-main').outerHeight() + $('#link-hobbies').outerHeight() + $('#link-portfolio').outerHeight() + $('#link-projects').outerHeight() + $('#nav').outerHeight() + 80; //получаемп значение высоты всех елементов для значение top
  $('footer').css({
    'top': height
  }); // применяем свойство к футеру
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Nunito+Sans|Roboto&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

html,
body,
header,
main {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-image: url(../images/extra_clean_paper.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#hero-header {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: dimgray;
  z-index: 2;
}

main:not {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 1em;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 3.125em 0.625em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.aboutme .col-40 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 39%;
}

.aboutme .col-60 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 59%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.hobbies .table-row {
  display: table-row;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid darkgrey;
}

.hobbies .table-row:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

.hobbies .table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.portfolio .col-50 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 49%;
}

.projects .flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.projects .col-33 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 33%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 33%;
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}

.projects .services-box {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 5px 0 5px;
}

footer {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header id="link-hero-page">
  <div id="hero-header">
  </div>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <section id="link-main" class="aboutme container">
    <div class="col-40 left">
    </div>
    <article class="col-60 right">
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="link-hobbies" class="hobbies container">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-row">
        <article class="table-cell">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
        </div>
        <article class="table-cell">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <article class="table-cell">
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="link-portfolio" class="portfolio container">
    <article class="col-50 left">
    </article>
    <article class="col-50 right">
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="link-projects" class="projects container">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="col-33">
        <article class="services-box">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-33">
        <article class="services-box">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-33">
        <article class="services-box">
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="link-contacts" class="contacts container">
  </section>
</main>
<!--FOOTER-->
<footer id='footer'>
   <address>
  <p style="text-align: center;">LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM</p>
 </address>
</footer>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```